# How to generate private function SELECT * FROM mass result?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function

I created two functions for downloading variables from database.
I do not know why but both queries return the same result. There is probably a solution that I am not aware of- but nothing comes to mind. Can you help me?

```
    public function A($A, $B) 
    {
        if(self::X() && count(self::X()) > NULL) 
        {
            $id2 = self::DB2();
            $this->id2 = $id2;

            $id3 = self::DB2();
            $this->id3 = $id3;

            self::Y();
            return true;

        } 
        else 
        {
            return false;           
        }       
    }
    private function DB2() 
    {    
            $id2 = BDR::selectBySQL("x1","SELECT * FROM id2 WHERE id='".$this->id1."' LIMIT 1");
            foreach($id2 as $id2) 
            {
                $id2 = $id2['id2'];

            }
            $id3 = BDR::selectBySQL("x1","SELECT * FROM id3 WHERE id='".$this->id3."' LIMIT 1");
            foreach($id3 as $id3) 
            {
                $id3 = $id3['id3'];

            }
            return $id2;
            return $id3;


    }
```

Comment: getByIdUz()   return always   $id2;  .. the second return ($id3) is never reached ..

Comment: he returns to me
but only that both are the same

Comment: you  should show also the  BDR::selectBySQL function  .because in your code is not clear if the query is executed  and how

Comment: also is not cleat the content for  $this->id1 and $this->id3 used in function  ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful your  getByIdUz() return always $id2; .. the second return ($id3) is never reached .
    if you want that teh function retunr two value  then you could return an array  eg:

```
 private function getByIdUz() 
{    
        $id2 = BDR::selectBySQL("x1","SELECT * FROM id2 WHERE id='".$this->id1."' LIMIT 1");
        foreach($id2 as $id2) 
        {
            $id2 = $id2['id2'];

        }
        $id3 = BDR::selectBySQL("x1","SELECT * FROM id3 WHERE id='".$this->id3."' LIMIT 1");
        foreach($id3 as $id3) 
        {
            $id3 = $id3['id3'];

        }
        return ['id2'=>$id2, 'id3', $id3];

}
```

and you could use

```
 $myArray = getByIdUz();

 $myId2 = $myArray['id2'];
 $myId3 = $myArray['id3'];
```

and in your

Comment: yeah of course, array, thanks sir, I would add your voice but I can only do it once I reach 15 reputations